# Pass ID from detail page to a VF page

Tags: custom-button, visualforce, url, detail-page

I have created a detail page button of Custom source as URL that has below URL

```
/apex/ComplianceIncidentPublish?Id={!Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Id}
```

That is unable to get hold of ID in the VF page. Can someone help please?

Comment: Are trying to fetch the id in vf page like by getparameterby('id')?

Comment: you'll need to post the relevant (and only the relevant - no code dumps please) bits of the corresponding VF page and VF controller (if any)

Comment: Is Compliance_Incident_abv__c a custom object? If yes & if the detail page button is on the Compliance_Incident_abv__c record itself, then your url should work. If Compliance_Incident_abv__c is a custom lookup or master-detail field then try this /apex/ComplianceIncidentPublish?Id={!Compliance_Incident_abvId__c}

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using this on the VF page:

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}
```

Or this in your actual APEX:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

See VF page param here: https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_query_params_getting.htm

and ApexPage APEX method here:
https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/apex_System_ApexPages_currentPage.htm

Answer (score -1):

The parameter you are passing is "Id" and you are checking for "ID"!